# primefaces dataTable: how to copy paste row

Tags: primefaces, datatable, copy-paste

I use primefaces,
my table has more than 75 column,
how to do when I want to copy row and paste it in the same table (of course change the PK after)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `<p:hotkey>` (to capture your copy and paste) along with the `selectionMode` attribute of `<p:dataTable>`

you can try:

```
<h:form>
   <p:hotkey bind="ctrl+c" actionListener="#{Bean.copy}"/>
   <p:hotkey bind="ctrl+s" actionListener="#{Bean.paste}"/>
   <p:dataTable id="dceTable" value="#{Bean.list}"
                var="row" selection="#{Bean.selection}"
                rowKey="#{row.seqNo}" >
      <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:30px;text-align:center" />
      ... insert your columns here
   </dataTable>
</h:form>
```

and your backing bean:

```
@Named("DCEBean")
@ViewScoped
public class Bean implements Serializable {

public void copy(){
// to copying codes like change PK
}

public void paste(){
// insert in your copied rows
}

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't out of the box. Only thing I can think of is to create a context menu and/or intercept the ctrl-v/c keys and call some backing bean methods that all does this for you. But that would be to complex of a solution to create for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but can you give as an example?

Comment: Please read the last sentence of my answer. If you break down this 'answer' you can find solutions on stackoverflow for each part.

Answer (score -1):

thank for all answers
but i have a little solution:

in the "list.xhtml" file and at context menu panel add the line:

```
<p:menuitem value="Copy" onclick="document.getElementById('CustomerListForm:copyButton').click();" icon="ui-icon-copy"/>
```

at the end of the file with other buttom add the line:

```
<p:commandButton id="copyButton"   style="visibility: hidden; icon="ui-icon-copy"   value="Copy" update=":CustomerCreateForm" oncomplete="PF('CustomerCreateDialog').show()"/>
```

**for more [click here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nz4RuBeLiRM)**

Comment: How is this an answer to the question?

Comment: This still is no answer to the original question. There is no list.xhtml in the Q, Links to Youtube video's (in French!!!) in answers are not in line with Stackoverflow 'rules/guidelines' etc...